# How to make the values in a datagridview columns to accounting format

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

How about this one, can you do me a little solution for this if you would mind?

I had this datagridview columns("Units") that has Negative Values in it;

```
Units
      3
     -3
      2
     -3
      3
     -2
Total 8
```

Now i want to convert Negative Values into (3) like this, below;

```
    Units
      3
     (3)
      2
     (3)
      3
     (2)
Total 8
```

How do i do this? Thanks a lot...

Comment: You want each negative value equals to 3 or each negative value turn into positive (like -3 -> 3 and -2 ->2)?

Comment: No. For example, i have value -3 that appears in the datagridview, but, instead of -3, i want to make it as (3), just like the accounting format in excel  .

Comment: DGV Columns include the ability to change the display format for the data

Answer (score 0):

You can use case when as below:

```
Select Case when Units < 0 then concat('(',abs(units),')') else convert(varchar(5), units) end as Units from yourtable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that like this :

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgvSubjects.Rows
    If row.Cells(3).Value < 0
        row.Cells(3).Value = 3
    End If
Next
```

**Hope it helped :)**

Comment: It does not changed the value at all bro..any other solution?

Comment: @Diaval .  Is `Cells(3)`  is the sell that contains the numbers?

Comment: @Diaval , It's that simple, you can see it here in this [clip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/w0xdjahjbxgdyji/Clip_4.mp4?dl=0).

Answer (score 0):

Considering that the column type is a string type, one possible solution is to use a `NumberFormat` to display negative numbers with parenthesis. [MSDN FormatNumber](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfta99yt(v=VS.90).aspx)

The fourth parameter `UseParensForNegativeNumbers` can be set to True with the `TriState` constant.

```
Dim numberString As String = FormatNumber(number, 0,, TriState.True,)
```

This should take the work out of removing the negative sign and adding the parenthesis. Below is a method that takes a number string and returns the same number string unless the string’s number value is less than zero (0), in which case will return the string with the negative sign removed and parenthesis added. If the string is not a number, the original string is returned.

```
Private Function GetAccountingNumber(originalString As String) As String
  If (Not (String.IsNullOrEmpty(originalString))) Then
    Dim number As Integer
    If (Integer.TryParse(originalString, number)) Then
      If (number < 0) Then
        Return FormatNumber(number, 0,, TriState.True,)
      Else
        Return originalString
      End If
    Else
      Return originalString
    End If
  Else
    Return ""
  End If
End Function
```

Given this, one place you may want to set this format is when the grids `CellValueChanged` event is fired for column 3. This would mean the cells value changed, and if it were a negative number, you would want to format that cell after the user leaves the cell. The grids `CellValueChanged` event may help for this… if the cell value changed is in column 3 then we want to format the cells value. Since we are changing the cells value, before setting the value, it is prudent to turn off this event to avoid a re-entrant error.

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellValueChanged(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellValueChanged
  If (e.RowIndex >= 0 And e.ColumnIndex = 3) Then
    If (DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(3).Value IsNot Nothing) Then
      RemoveHandler DataGridView1.CellValueChanged, AddressOf DataGridView1_CellValueChanged
      DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(3).Value = GetAccountingNumber(DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(3).Value.ToString())
      AddHandler DataGridView1.CellValueChanged, AddressOf DataGridView1_CellValueChanged
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

I am guessing this is what you are looking for. Hope it helps.